# What is the fastest way to brute for a SHA-1 hash?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash

I have a hash and the full decrypted plaintext of that hash.  I am planning on trying to brute force it, it's a SHA-1 FIPS 180-2 hash.

So my question is, what is the fastest way of doing this?  I was thinking about decrypting the data and comparing it to the known plaintext, but then I thought it may be faster to try to hash the decrypted data and compare it to the known hash.
Hopefully the above makes sense, but just incase, the main question is this:

```
Plaintext : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Hash : 2FD4E1C67A2D28FCED849EE1BB76E7391B93EB12
```

Is is faster to try to hash Plaintext, and compare it to the hash, or decrypt Hash and compare it to Plaintext?  Any advice on how to speed up recovery of the key is appreciated.  This is just me playing about, I know it would take forever to find the key, but if it were possible to do in a small amount of time (HUUUUGE computing power), how would you do do it?

Comment: How can you decrypt a hash since it's a one-way function which loses information about the initial data? These is difference between a _cipher text_ and a _hashcode_.

Comment: @Sam - This could have legitimate security purposes. I'd give the benefit of the doubt. Vijay - The [tag:language-agnostic] tag may still be around, but please don't tag it with languages that aren't specifically involved.

Comment: @Sam There are legitimate reasons to do this - don't second guess.

Comment: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9227834/LinkedIn_confirms_some_passwords_leaked_ - related?

Comment: What do you mean by 'decrypt hash'? What is a 'key' in this context?

Comment: @NikhilDabas That was in my mind too...

Comment: I'm not trying to actually do this.  An no @TravisJ, I'm not trying to get peoples passwords... I'm just asking what the fastest way to do this would be.  I apologize for not using the correct terms, I'm not a security person and I know very little about cryptography!

Comment: @JustinMorgan, sorry, didn't know that tag existed!  I'll remember it for next time! :)

Comment: @Vijay - You may get a better response on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ (you may even find an existing answer if you search).

Comment: So, a hash is a one way thing, hashing must require a key.  So I would HAVE to try to hash my plaintext and see if it matches my known hash?  OK, well that kinda answers my question! :)

And to put everyone's mind at rest, this was just something that popped into my head whilst listening to an audiobook on "Cryptography for beginners".  Again, sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @JamesAllardice - wow, didn't even know that existed!  Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a hash and the full decrypted plaintext of that hash. I am
>   planning on trying to brute force it, it's a SHA-1 FIPS 180-2 hash.

So you have the hash and the plaintext?

Find an implementation of SHA and verify it.  That is all you can do.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was trying to ask.  I guess I'm using the wrong terms and/or don't understand enough from my 50 pages of "Cryptography for beginners" book!  I'll read up some more and come back with a question that doesn't get down-voted to hell! :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think people would be so mad that I didn't understand things that well.  I guess its a lesson learnt!  Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

As is (almost) always the case, using someone else's code is faster than writing your own.  [oclHashcat-plus](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/) is a pretty good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted you as you tried to help.  I was wondering what would be faster out of my two choices, but it turns out there is only one choice!  So I'm all set... 

Thanks again!